# focus to the next input in datatable with jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf, datatables

I would like to make a focus to the next input in a table with jquery. I have this table in jsf.

```
<p:dataTable id="resu" value="#{onController.items}"  var="item" >

   <p:column id="colIn" >

     <h:inputText  id="i"  value="#{item.cup}"  />

   <p:column>

<p:dataTable>
```

was tested with this:

```
function nexts(input) {
   $(input).next("input[type=text]").focus();
}
```

`onkeyup="nexts(this)"` in the input

It does not work between rows only with inputs followed.

Comment: Seriously, please edit your question. Select the code and then hit the `101010` button (or ctrl+K) to format the code **as** code. Also, for JS/jQuery the rendered code (view source) is more important than the server-side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `next()` only searches in the siblings. The datatable renders a HTML `<table>` with rows in `<tr>` elements. Rightclick the page in webbrowser and choose *View Source*. You should base your JS/jQuery code on this (simply because that's basically all what it can see). Technically, you should go up to the closest `<tr>`, then go to the next `<tr>` and finally find the next input element in there.

```
$(input).closest('tr').next('tr').find('input[type=text]').focus();
```

Comment: thank you very much I'm just starting with jquery. that way works fine.